# Creating system to give point to 3 employees, every time I click on one of the button I gives 1 point to the selected user-

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```js
// Declare Variables
var madsPoint, lindaPoint, peterPoint, resultatContainer, voteContainer

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button') // Henter alle elementer i dokumentet med class = "button"

// Variabler point declare and assign
var point = {   
    mads: 0,
    linda: 0,
    peter: 0
  }
votes = (vote, amount) => {

 // Print names for votes
    var targ = document.getElementsByClassName(vote)[0].children[0]
    targ.innerText = parseInt(targ.innerText) + amount
    nameValg.innerText = `You voted on ${vote}`
    var string = "You got a vote " + vote + '!' 
    resultatContainer.innerText = string
    
    point[vote] += amount
    setTimeout(()=>{evalPoints(vote)}, 50) // Vises den nedståede alarmboks efter 2 sekunder (2000 millisekunder): 
}

//  the first user get 30 or more point wins and an alert says no more votes 
evalPoints = (vote) =>{
  if (point[vote] >= 30) {
    alert(`No more votes. ${vote} is the winner!`)
    resetScore() // socering vil blive restet efterfølgende
  }
}

// Set event handles for each button
buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', e => {
      // Assign data attribute to variable
      let targ = e.target
      let vote = targ.dataset.type
      let amount = parseInt(targ.value) //konveter string (text) til tal.
      e.preventDefault()
      votes(vote, amount)
    })
})

// Resetscore after the first user gets the  30  eller mere point
resetScore = () =>{
  
    point = {mads: 0, linda: 0, peter: 0}     
    madsPoint.innerText = 0
    lindaPoint.innerText = 0
    peterPoint.innerText = 0
 }

 // når det oprindelige HTML-dokument er blevet indlæst. så vil denne begivenhed blive indlæst.
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  // returnerer det første element i dokumentet, der matcher den specificerede vælger.navn plus point (madspoint) osv.
    madsPoint = document.querySelector('.mads .point')
    lindaPoint = document.querySelector('.linda .point')
    peterPoint = document.querySelector('.peter .point')
    resultatContainer = document.querySelector('.resultat')
    nameValg = document.querySelector('.nameValg')




    var  chart = document.getElementById("itChart");


   // Global Options
   Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "Lato";
   Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 18;
   Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = "#777";

    var itChart = new Chart(chart, {
        type:"bar", // alle type diagramer.
        data:{
            labels:["Mads", "Linda", "Peter"],
            datasets:[{
                label:"Point pr. Supporter",
                data:[
                    30, 18, 25,],

               // backgroundColor
               backgroundColor:[
                
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)',
    
               ],
               borderWidth:0,
               borderColor:[
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)',
            
            ], 
               hoverBorderWidth:2,
               hoverBorderColor:"#000"
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true
                 }
            }]
        },
    legend:{
        display:true,
        position:"top",
        labels:{
            fontColor:"#000"
        }
 
   
    },
    tooltips:{
       enabled:true
    }
}
});



});
```

```html
<html lang="da">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>PointSystem</title>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    

  </head>
<body>

    <h4>Her vises point. Alle hold starter med 0 point</h4> 
    <div class="mads">Point til Mads: <span class="point">0</span></div>
    <button data-type="mads" value="1">Mindre Godt</button>
    <button data-type="mads" value="3">Godt</button>
    <button data-type="mads" value="5">Rigtig Godt</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="linda">Point til Linda: <span class="point">0</span></div>
    <button data-type="linda" value="1">Mindre Godt</button>
    <button data-type="linda" value="3">Godt</button>
    <button data-type="linda" value="5">Rigtig Godt</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="peter">Point til Peter: <span class="point">0</span></div>
    <button data-type="peter" value="1">Mindre Godt</button>
    <button data-type="peter" value="3">Godt</button>
    <button data-type="peter" value="5">Rigtig Godt</button>
    <br>
  
    <h4>Her vises resultat Navn på hvem fik en stemme ind</h4>
    <div class="nameValg"></div>
  
    <h4>Her vises resultat Navn for hvert stemme der kommer ind</h4>
    <div class="resultat"></div>



    <div style= "width: 60%;">
      <canvas id="itChart" width="750" height="450"></canvas>
    





    </body>

</html>
```

I'm new to programming, and I can't get what I'm doing wrong in this:
I'm trying creating a system to give point to 3 employees,(
assessment the employees by giving point, the employee getting most points to get a present) every time I click on one of the buttons I give 1 point to the selected user- and the point increases every time I click on the same user, then if I want to give point to another user, I just click on the other user. but my code does not work-

Here is my HTML code and JavaScript code-

```js
// Declare Variables
var madsPoint, lindaPoint, peterPoint, resultatContainer, voteContainer, stemPaa2Container

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button')

// Variabler point declare and assign
var point = {   
    mads: 0,
    linda: 0,
    peter: 0
  }

  function votes(vote) {

 // Print names for votes
 var targ = document.getElementsByClassName(vote)[0].children[0]
 targ.innerText = parseInt(targ.innerText) + 1
 nameValg.innerText = `You voted on ${vote}`
 
 var str = "Yo got a vote " + vote + '!' 
    resultatContainer.innerText = str 
    
    point[vote] += 1
    setTimeout(()=>{evalPoints()}, 100)
}


//  the first user get 10 point wins and an alert says no more votes 
const evalPoints = () =>{
 if (point.mads=== 10) {
 alert('No more votes. Mads is the winner!')
 resetScore()
 } else if (point.linda === 10) {
 alert('No more votes. Linda is the winner!')
 resetScore()
 } else if (point.peter === 10){
  alert('No more votes. Peter is the winner!')
  resetScore()
 }
}

// Set event handles for each button
buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', e => {
      // Assign data attribute to variable
      let vote = e.target.dataset.type 
      e.preventDefault()
      votes(vote)
    })
    })


// Reset score after the first user gets the 10 point
const resetScore = () =>{
    point = {mads: 0, linda: 0, peter: 0}
  
    madsPoint.innerText = 0
    lindaPoint.innerText = 0
    peterPoint.innerText = 0
  }

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    madsPoint = document.querySelector('.mads .point')
    lindaPoint = document.querySelector('.linda .point')
    peterPoint = document.querySelector('.peter .point')
    resultatContainer = document.querySelector('.resultat')
    nameValg = document.querySelector('.nameValg')
   });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="da">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>PointSystem</title>
  </head>
<body>

    <h4>Her vises point. Alle hold starter med 0 point</h4> 
    <div class="mads">Point til Mads: <span class="point">0</span></div>
    <button data-type="mads">En point til Mads</button>
    <button data-type="mads">To point til Mads</button>
    <button data-type="mads">Tre point til Mads</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="linda">Point til Linda: <span class="point">0</span></div>
    <button data-type="linda">En point til Linda</button>
    <button data-type="linda">To point til Linda</button>
    <button data-type="linda">Tre point til Linda</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="peter">Point til Peter: <span class="point">0</span></div>
    <button data-type="peter">En point til Peter</button>
    <button data-type="peter">To point til Peter</button>
    <button data-type="peter">Tre point til Peter</button>
    <br>
  
    <h4>Her vises resultat hvem fik en stemme ind</h4>
    <div class="nameValg"></div>
  
    <h4>Her vises resultat for hvert stemme der kommer ind</h4>
    <div class="resultat"></div>

    <h4>plus alle point</h4>
    <div class="pluspoint"></div>
    <button data-type="pluspoint">Plus alle point</button>
    </body>
<script src="IT.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: You haven't provided any javascript code

Comment: Hi im new to this forum, and I do not know if I did wrong, but the code is the snippet, if you cannot see it, would you please guide me on how to share the code-
Thanx

Comment: Ah I see it now

Comment: Are you just trying to update the point next to the name if you click on the name?

Comment: yes that what I had in mind :) Thanx,  now I want to build more to the program ,
thanx for the help, lets see if I can build more on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might want to refactor your code a bit and wrap your `querySelector`'s in an onload event listener because (at least for me) the variables are all undefined. You should wait until the content (class names etc.) are already rendered onto the DOM.

Then you need to wrap your point check in a function that gets called at the end of your point assignment. Otherwise the check will only be called when the JS file initially loads. I put the point evaluation in the `evalPoints` function and added it at the end of the point assignment function so that so the check gets run every time you add a point.

You also don't appear to have `resetScore` declared anywhere so I added that as well.

```js
// const er variabler som declare en værdi men kan ikke assignes igen.
var madsPoint, lindaPoint, peterPoint, resultatContainer, madsValgContainer, lindaValgContainer, peterValgContainer

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button')

// Point variabler som declare en værdi
var point = {   
    mads: 0,
    linda: 0,
    peter: 0
  }

  function stem(madsValg) {

 // Print navne stemer
 
  var targ = document.getElementsByClassName(madsValg)[0].children[0]
 
  targ.innerText = parseInt(targ.innerText) + 1
  
  nameValg.innerText = `Du stemt på ${madsValg}`
  
  var str = "Det Du fik en stemme " + madsValg + '!' 
     resultatContainer.innerText = str 
     
     point[madsValg] += 1
     setTimeout(()=>{evalPoints()}, 100)
}

const evalPoints = () =>{
  if (point.mads === 3) {
  alert('Du vandt!')
  resetScore()
  } else if (point.linda === 3) {
  alert('Du vandt')
  resetScore()
  } else if (point.peter === 3){
   alert('Du vandt')
   resetScore()
  }
}
// if hvis spiller vinder 3 gang så kommer der en alert at Spiller vandt 

// Sæt begivenhedshåndterere til hver knap
buttons.forEach(button => {
button.addEventListener('click', e => {
  // Tildel dataattribut til variabel
  let madsValg = e.target.dataset.type 
  e.preventDefault()
  // Vælge Spillervalg til  SSP = Sten Saks Papir Spil
  stem(madsValg)
})
})

const resetScore = () =>{
  point = {mads: 0, linda: 0, peter: 0}

  madsPoint.innerText = 0
  lindaPoint.innerText = 0
  peterPoint.innerText = 0
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
 madsPoint = document.querySelector('.mads .point')
 lindaPoint = document.querySelector('.linda .point')
 peterPoint = document.querySelector('.peter .point')
 resultatContainer = document.querySelector('.resultat')
 nameValg = document.querySelector('.nameValg')
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="da">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>PointSystem</title>
  </head>
<body>
    <h4>Her vises point. Alle hold starter med 0 point</h4> 
    <div class="mads">Mads Point: <span class="point">0</span></div>
    <div class="linda">Linda Point: <span class="point">0</span></div>
    <div class="peter">Peter Point: <span class="point">0</span></div>

    <h4>Valg hvem du vil stemme på</h4> 
    <button data-type="mads">Mads</button>
    <button data-type="linda">Linda</button>
    <button data-type="peter">Peter</button>

    <div class="nameValg"></div>
  
    <h4>Her vises resultat for hvert stemme der kommer ind</h4>
    <div class="resultat"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanx Matt Croak, it helps, now I want to build more into the program :)

Comment: Hi again,  I'm now having issues with incremental plus the data, I have created for each user, 3 buttons each button give different points. Button 1 gives 1 point to user 1, button 2 gives 2 points to user 1 and button 3 gives 3 points to user1. Then a function adds both the value from button 1, buttons 2 and button 3.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want the plus point button to do but I made [this codepen](https://codepen.io/macro6461/pen/gOpdWRX?editors=1010) to illustrate how to assign a number value to each button and since there is the possibility that the final vote count could be greater than 10 (if someone clicks button3 four times) I changed the conditional in `evalPoints` to check if the votes are `>= 10`.

Comment: Thanx, it gives sense.

Comment: If I want the point data, get automatically updated into the chart, is there a way to do it, I have inserted the HTML and JAVAScript code into the snipper.